# Component not accessing context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm new to react please forgive me if i'm asking a dumb question. 
The idea is to access the tweets array from context, find the matching tweet and then set it in the component's state to access the data.

However, the tweets array results empty even though i'm sure it's populated with tweets

```
   const { tweets } = useContext(TweeetterContext)
   const [tweet, setTweet] = useState({})

   useEffect(() => {
      loadData(match.params.id, tweets)
   }, [])

   const loadData = (id, tweets) => {
      return tweets.filter(tweet => tweet.id == id)
   }
   return (stuff)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing context perfectly fine, and it would be good if you could share a code where you set `tweets`.

Independent of that, potential problem I might spot here is related to the `useEffect` function. You are using variables from external context (`match.params.id` and `tweets`), but you are not setting them as dependencies. Because of that your `useEffect` would be run only once at the initial creation of component.
The actual problem might be that `tweets` are set **after** this initial creation (there is some delay for setting correct value to the `tweets`, for example because of the network request).

Try using it like this, and see if it fixes the issue:

```
useEffect(() => {
   loadData(match.params.id, tweets)
}, [match.params.id, tweets])
```

Also, not sure what your `useEffect` is actually doing, as it's not assigning the result anywhere, but I'm going to assume it's just removed for code snippet clarity.